# How to limit visibility of enum values in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, enums, namespaces, visibility, typedef

In Objective C, when you define an enum, all of the enum values are visible everywhere and clog the global namespace.

I would like to make it Java-style and enforce that enums are only accessible thru the enum type name, e.g. with

```
typedef enum
{
MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY, NUM_OF
} Day;
```

I want to make sure that 
simply calling `MONDAY` produces compilation error or at least warning, and the only way to access the enum value were something like `Day.MONDAY` or `Day::MONDAY` or `[Day MONDAY]` or...

In Java I either use Enums or Interfaces, but is this doable in Objective-C?

If not, then I'd have to name all enums like this: `DAY_MONDAY, DAY_TUESDAY...` to make them easier to seach in auto-completion pop-up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a workaround, but you can create a custom interface with a number of class methods (so that there's no need to create an instance), where each method represent a constant.

This way constants will be accessible only as you asked (ie. `Day.MONDAY` or `[Day MONDAY]`).

Comment: There is no such thing as C++/Java-style static class variables, right? That's why class methods.. Thx for your idea, it will work, yet of course defining all those methods would be too much typing..