# Usage of enum name as value identifier in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, enums, namespaces, declaration, redefinition

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388997/how-to-limit-visibility-of-enum-values-in-objective-c) it seems that there is no possibility in Objective-C to define two `enum`s with the same value as in this example:

```cpp
enum AnEnum {
  AnyValue
};

enum AnotherEnum {
  AnyValue // Error: Redefinition of enumerator 'AnyValue'
};
```

I would like to understand the backgrounds why an opportunity of setting names for `enum`s is available but apparently without any possibility to make use of it (e.g. like in Java by calling values via `AnotherEnum.AnyValue`).

Comment: you set the name and you can use it, what you can't do is to scope your usage, but scope is a broader issue in Obj-C and there are conventions to work around that

Comment: Yes, sorry, my post was a bit too generic ... so you can for example define variables of the `enum` type (which then also results in context sensitive code support), but what I am missing are two aspects.

Comment: 1) I would like to understand the backgrounds why the above mentioned restriction is present in objective-c and 2) what the most common work around is.

Comment: There is a trick you can use to make a `struct` work like a namespaced `enum`, demonstrated by Mike Ash at his blog: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-08-19-namespaced-constants-and-functions.html

Comment: @JoshCaswell Cool pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C is C. An `enum` is a C enum. And there is no namespacing. That is exactly why the convention is to name the enumerations AnEnumAnyValue and AnotherEnumAnyValue. You'll find that all Cocoa enumerations work that way:

```
typedef enum {
   UIViewAnimationTransitionNone,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp,
   UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown,
} UIViewAnimationTransition;
```

If you want scoped enumeration names like Java, switch to Swift.